# Histogram of ECG image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I want to ask how to find histogram of ECG image?
As my program gives following error:

```
Function IMHIST expected its first input, I or X, to be two-dimensional.

Error in ==> imhist>parse_inputs at 216
iptcheckinput(a, {'double','uint8','logical','uint16','int16','single'}, ...

Error in ==> imhist at 57
[a, n, isScaled, top, map] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

My program is:

```
Im1 = imread('pic1.jpg');Im = im2double(Im1);figure,imhist(Im)
```

Comment: Haven't used im2double or a while, but sounds like it returns a w x h x 3 tensor of r-g-b-data and not a 2D matrix.

Comment: @ThePadawan: im2double simply re-casts and, I think, rescales the image. It won't affect its dimensions. The dimensions depend on how the image was stored, and JPG are often stored as RGB.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the image is stored as RGB. Consequently, you have to transform it to grayscale:

```
Im1 = imread('pic1.jpg');
Im = im2double(Im1);
Im = rgb2gray(Im); %# convert to grayscale
figure,imhist(Im)
```